# Update Exchange Server Certificate in C#

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, exchange-server, x509certificate2

My goal is to update the Certificate for Exchange Servers from within a C# app, just like the `Enable-ExchangeCertificate` PS Cmdlet does.

I've already written an updater for IIS, which uses `Microsoft.Web.Administration` to access and manipulate IIS Sites and Bindings. I've searched through Google and VS Libraries for Exchange API tools, but without any luck. I can only find References to EWS (Exchange Web Services), which can't update the Server Certificate AFAIK.

Is there any API that can be used? How does `Enable-ExchangeCertificate` provide the functionality? I'm also thinking about just using the PS Cmdlet if all else fails, but I'd like to have a standalone app to rely on. No remote server management needed, localhost-only is fine.

tl;dr How to update a local Exchange Server Certificate in C#?

**EDIT** I'll look further into the EWS API (https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/blob/master/README.md), it looks like it might do the job. It provides Assemblies to access EWS data, but I haven't found any API Calls exclusively for Certificate Management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple parts in MS Exchange which aren´t covered by an API. Mostly this is due to security reasons or as it´s quite complex and therefore no API needed (e.g. Exchange Schema update).

The normal Microsoft way included only two steps:

1. Make a Backup of the current configuration & SSL cert (Optional)
2. Import the certificate

> Import-ExchangeCertificate -FileData ([Byte[]]$(Get-Content -Path
>   c:\certificates\YOUR_CERTIFICATE.cer -Encoding byte -ReadCount 0))

*But some use MMC and that's working as well (so you might check for an API for MMC for this part).*

3. Enable it

> Enable-ExchangeCertificate -Thumbprint
>   1234ae0567a72fccb75b1d0198628675333d010e -Services POP,IMAP,SMTP,IIS

I would assume that there is no such API as its not really needed to have one. Normally an SSL certificate is valid for 3 years. So you need to run the command above 1x every 3 years and a 3rd party access to this part wouldn´t make any sense as it wouldn´t be often used and therefore Microsoft haven´t build one.

To give you more infos here. The SSL certificate information for Microsoft is saved in two locations. One in the local Regestry and one in Microsoft Active Directory (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997231(v=exchg.160).aspx): uses the local instance of Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS) to read and write data). Dealing with changes to the ActiveDirectory without the way Microsoft supports might be VERY risky and would mean that Microsoft do not offer any support if that caused a problem. So I would use the powershell approach Enable-ExchangeCertificate in your app.

*P.S. I would never ever run an unknown plugin on my Exchange server which do replace an SSL certificate which I can do via a simple powershell command. The plugin could cause a lot of other issues and can contain a lot of stuff which isn´t so "nice". So before you wast your time into that project think if there is really an audience for it.*

Comment: OK, I'll just call Enable-ExchangeCertificate from my app then. I'm looking to automatically import and enable certs from Let's Encrypt. BTW Import from encrypted PFX Files works seamless through the provided system libs in dotnet. The PFX passphrase is stored only in encrypted form on disk, an attacker would need knowledge of that encryption key to do something malicious, ie. install a malicious certificate. Thanks for that load of information, I should've done some more research before asking...

Comment: Ah i see. There is a LetsEncrypt Powershell module. Maybe you wish to involve that one in your application as well so that you do not need to re-invent the whole weel. However what i would prefer would be a complete powershell script instean an C# app then.

Comment: I tried some solutions for LE on Windows, IMO the linux clients are more stable/work better. A pure PS solution would be nice, but for linux compatibility I use getssl, pack and encrypt with openssl, then push the output  to a Windows share, where my service can pick it up, import and enable for IIS bindings and Exchange.